# Menu drawer is not working in hybrid app in android by phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I created a android apk by using phonegap. menu drawer is working properly in html code but it is not working in android device. when i click on menu icon i dnt get any response. so am attaching screenshot of html view [image]

[image]

this the screenshot of html page view but in android menu drawer is not working. html coding is showing below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="sidebar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="swipe-area"></div>
          <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle"> <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span> </a>
          <div class="content">
            <h1>Hybrid App</h1>
            <div class="jquery-script-ads"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
/* jQuery_demo */
google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>

</div> </div>

 <div class="para">
            <p>Hybrid Mobile Applications. Hybrid development combines the best (or worst) of both the native and HTML5 worlds. We define hybrid as a web app, primarily built using HTML5 and JavaScript, that is then wrapped inside a thin native container that provides access to native platform features.</p>

         </div>

         <div>
           <a href=""><img src="www/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png\native_html_hybrid_apps_development_1920_700_1.jpg" width="1300" height="700" alt=""></a>
         </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script> 
      <script>
  $(window).load(function(){
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
          var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
          $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
        });
         $(".swipe-area").swipe({
              swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
                  {
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="right") {
                           $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="left") {
                           $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                  }
          }); 
      });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code so please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please register your events like that.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
        app.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () { 

        capp.bindEvents();

    }
};
var capp = {

    bindEvents: function () {
}
};
```

you have to register every event because all the events will work after deviceready event.So simply use this structure and define all events in capp.
thanks